# Query MAC address with Safari (on MAC OS)

Tags: macos, safari, safari-extension

My webapp has a function that inquires the client MAC address using browser's JavaScript.
I have implemented this for Windows's environment browsers such as Chrome, Firefox and IE. But I got stuck for MacOS's Safari. I followed a suggestion also from this site, implied that a Safari's extension is capable of fulfill this. But before digging into developing one, may someone give me a clue where to start.

I also found an article in this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/GetPrimaryMACAddress/Introduction/Intro.html

Is there someway to create an extension to access that code from Safari?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution with Firebreath. With this I can create a plugin for all common browsers on both Windows and MacOS X in a feasible and consistent way.
Thanks for considers.